# How can I get two divs, one with multiple nested divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this kind of question has been asked before, but the solutions listed there did not work for me.

I have two divs, one with text and the other one has multiple divs, in a nested structure. I want them placed beside each other. I tried `display: inline-block` as most solutions pointed out, but they did not work for me.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="close-date-div">Close Date:
    <div class="form-group" id="close_date">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <span class="input-group-addon" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>  
            <input class="form-control" id="close_date_input" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is the output I am getting for that code snippet, how can make it so that `Close Date` and the input box are on the same line?

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `#close_date {display: inline-block;}`?

Comment: @Sébastien I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: @RickHitchcock Doing that results in this: https://imagebin.ca/v/3qnyBJcsOIuU

Comment: @Di437 I would recommend adding the `bootstrap` and/or `bootstrap3` tag to the post, since you are using well-known bootstrap style classes in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is very opinionated when it comes to forms. If you use the provided classes you have a limited set of possible presentations.

You could set your form to use [form-inline](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline) or maybe [form-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal)

Here I had to use xs because the snippet window is too small to trigger any other break point. You will also have to tweek column widths and vertical alignment.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="close-date-div">

    <div class="form-group" id="close_date">
      <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Close Date:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="input-group date">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          <input class="form-control" id="close_date_input" value="" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, after an hour or so of constant debugging, refreshing the browser and banging my head over the keyboard, this WORKS! `form-horizontal` was perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Make your text some king of html element. In this case a made it a paragraph element with the `<p>` tag

Hope this helps!

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="close-date-div">
  <p class="inline">Close Date:</p>
  <div class="form-group  inline" id="close_date">
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input class="form-control" id="close_date_input" value="" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does the same thing as making `#close_date` `display: inline-block`
Here: https://imagebin.ca/v/3qnyBJcsOIuU

Comment: @Di437 can i get the rest of the css or a live example. It is important to keep all of your content inside html tags that correspond to the content. This is one of the first thing html5 brought to us.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but my rep isn't high enough yet.

I dealt with this recently, and I had to make sure that the positions were all set in order for the display: `inline-block` to work. I believe the following example should get you where you need to be.

```
.close-date-div{
  position: relative;
}

.form-group{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-group date{
  position:sticky;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div class="close-date-div">
```

To

```
<div class="close-date-div form-inline">
```

You may also want to add `form-group`.  Note, this solution is specific to boostrap-only because you've shared code which is utilizing well-known bootstrap classes.